# Tap gesture causes strange behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, uigesturerecognizer

I’m building a reaction test that requires the user to tap on the target dot, while other non-target dots come down.  It works most of the time but sometimes after tapping on a target dot it will display several other dots with weird behavior.  I’ve been looking at the code for days and I can’t find the problem.  Does anyone have any suggestions?
Thanks much.  Here’s the code.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // single tap gesture recognizer
    self.myTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(theTap:)];
    self.myTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [self.firstView addGestureRecognizer:self.myTap];

    self.myTap.enabled = NO;

    self.colorToHit = self.colorFromPreviousController;

    [self KickOff];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.holdTheReactionTimes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:50];
    self.firstTime = YES;
    numberOfTries = 0;

}

#pragma mark - Utility Methods
- (void)setRandomLocationForView:(UIView *)view
{

    CGRect sinkBounds = CGRectInset(self.firstView.bounds, view.frame.size.width/2, view.frame.size.height/2);

    CGFloat x = arc4random() % (int)sinkBounds.size.width + view.frame.size.width/2;
    CGFloat y = arc4random() % (int)sinkBounds.size.height + view.frame.size.height/2;

    view.center = CGPointMake(x, y);
}

- (void)addLabel
{
    [self stopDraining];

    static NSArray *buttons = nil;

    buttons = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
               @"XX.png",
               @"YY.png",
               @"ZZ.png",
               nil];

    int theIndex = arc4random()%[buttons count]; 
    NSLog(@"the index: %d", theIndex);
    NSString *theImageName = [buttons objectAtIndex:theIndex];
    CGRect anotherFrame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 64, 64);
    UIView *anotherView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:anotherFrame]
    UIImageView  *imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-2, -2, 64, 64)];
    imageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:theImageName];
    [anotherView addSubview:imageView1];

    [self setRandomLocationForView:anotherView];
    [self.firstView addSubview:anotherView];

    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    timeOne = [date timeIntervalSince1970];    
    if (theIndex == self.colorToHit) {
        NSLog(@"the right color");
        self.isThisTheRightColor = YES;
        self.myTap.enabled = YES;
        numberOfTries += 1;

    } else {
        NSLog(@"the wrong color");
        self.isThisTheRightColor = NO;
        self.myTap.enabled = NO;
        [self startDraining];
    }
}

#pragma mark - View Animation
#define ANIMATE_DURATION 6.0
#define SLEEP_INTERVAL 0.5

- (void)theTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    NSLog(@"Tapped");

    float tapInterval = 0;
    CGPoint tapLocation = [gesture locationInView:self.firstView];
    for (UIView *view in self.firstView.subviews) {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, tapLocation)) {
            NSLog(@"we hit one");
            AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate); // added this 4-27

            if (self.firstTime) {
                NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
                timeTwo = [date timeIntervalSince1970];
                NSLog(@"TAP First time: %f", timeTwo);
                self.firstTime = NO;
            } else {

                NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
                timeTwo = [date timeIntervalSince1970];
                NSLog(@"Second time: %f", timeTwo);
            }

            tapInterval = (timeTwo - timeOne);
            NSLog(@"Time Interval: %f", tapInterval);

            [view removeFromSuperview];

            [self writeTimeStampToArray:tapInterval];
        }
    }
}

- (void)KickOff
{
    for (UIView *view in self.firstView.subviews) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }

    if (self.firstView.window) {
        [self addLabel];
    }    
}

- (void)writeTimeStampToArray:(float)timeStamp
{
    NSNumber *timeObject = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: timeStamp];
    [self.holdTheReactionTimes addObject:timeObject];

    if (numberOfTries < NUMBER_OF_TRIES) {
        [self addLabel];
    } else {
        [self nextScreen];
    }
}

- (void)nextScreen
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"viewsummary" sender: self];
}

    }
}

#pragma mark - Flipside View

- (void)ReactionViewControllerDidFinish:(int)trynumber
{
    self.tryNumberInt = trynumber;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}

#define COUNTER 4

//////////////
// drain logic

- (void)drain:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    [self drain];
}

#define DRAIN_DURATION 2.0

- (void)startDraining
{
    self.drainTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:DRAIN_DURATION/3
                                                       target:self
                                                     selector:@selector(drain:)
                                                     userInfo:nil
                                                      repeats:YES]; 
}

- (void)stopDraining
{
    [self.drainTimer invalidate];
}

- (void)drain
{
    for (UIView *view in self.firstView.subviews) {
        CGAffineTransform transform = view.transform;
        if (CGAffineTransformIsIdentity(transform)) {
            UIViewAnimationOptions options = UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear;
            [UIView animateWithDuration:DRAIN_DURATION/3 delay:0 options:options animations:^{
                view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 0.7, 0.7), 2*M_PI/3);
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                if (finished) {
                    [UIView animateWithDuration:DRAIN_DURATION/3 delay:0 options:options animations:^{
                        view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 0.4, 0.4), -2*M_PI/3);
                    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                        if (finished) {
                            [UIView animateWithDuration:DRAIN_DURATION/3 delay:0 options:options animations:^{
                                view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 0.1, 0.1);
                            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                if (finished) [view removeFromSuperview];
                            }];
                        }
                    }];
                }
            }];
        }
    }

    [self addLabel];

}
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging, breaking on the tap of a dot and then adding breakpoints on dot creation and movement?

Comment: Did you checked the state of `UITapGestureRecognizer`. try only act when the state is equals to `UITapGestureRecognizerStateEnded`.